# can't serialize session for resin request

Tags: java, session, resin

```
[13-04-27 11:27:30.890] {resin-port-10.156.76.24:8084-48} SessionImpl[aaaJ3Dcydow_igIqaIj5t,]: can't serialize session
java.lang.IllegalStateException: block Block[Table[mnode:2],72002] is not an index code=0
    at com.caucho.db.block.Block.validateIsIndex(Block.java:152)
    at com.caucho.db.index.BTree.validateIndex(BTree.java:1727)
    at com.caucho.db.index.BTree.lookup(BTree.java:197)
    at com.caucho.db.index.BTree.lookup(BTree.java:212)
    at com.caucho.db.index.BTree.lookup(BTree.java:168)
    at com.caucho.db.sql.IndexExpr.evalIndex(IndexExpr.java:152)
    at com.caucho.db.sql.IndexExpr.initRow(IndexExpr.java:104)
    at com.caucho.db.sql.Query$TailInitRow.initBlockRow(Query.java:952)
    at com.caucho.db.sql.Query.start(Query.java:727)
    at com.caucho.db.sql.SelectQuery.execute(SelectQuery.java:209)
    at com.caucho.db.sql.SelectQuery.execute(SelectQuery.java:171)
    at com.caucho.db.jdbc.PreparedStatementImpl.execute(PreparedStatementImpl.java:357)
    at com.caucho.db.jdbc.PreparedStatementImpl.executeQuery(PreparedStatementImpl.java:325)
    at com.caucho.server.distcache.MnodeStore.load(MnodeStore.java:535)
    at com.caucho.server.distcache.CacheDataBackingImpl.loadLocalEntryValue(CacheDataBackingImpl.java:108)
    at com.caucho.server.distcache.DistCacheEntry.loadLocalMnodeValue(DistCacheEntry.java:1189)
    at com.caucho.server.distcache.CacheEntryManager.createCacheEntry(CacheEntryManager.java:83)
    at com.caucho.server.distcache.CacheStoreManager.getCacheEntry(CacheStoreManager.java:143)
    at com.caucho.server.distcache.CacheImpl.getDistCacheEntry(CacheImpl.java:663)
    at com.caucho.server.distcache.CacheImpl.put(CacheImpl.java:459)
    at com.caucho.server.session.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:906)
    at com.caucho.server.session.SessionImpl.saveAfterRequest(SessionImpl.java:869)
    at com.caucho.server.session.SessionImpl.finishRequest(SessionImpl.java:645)
    at com.caucho.server.http.AbstractCauchoRequest.finishRequest(AbstractCauchoRequest.java:1047)
    at com.caucho.server.http.HttpServletRequestImpl.finishRequest(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:1692)
    at com.caucho.server.http.AbstractHttpRequest.finishRequest(AbstractHttpRequest.java:1848)
    at com.caucho.server.http.HttpRequest.finishRequest(HttpRequest.java:1487)
    at com.caucho.server.http.HttpRequest.handleRequest(HttpRequest.java:870)
    at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketLink.dispatchRequest(TcpSocketLink.java:1342)
    at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketLink.handleRequest(TcpSocketLink.java:1298)
    at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketLink.handleRequestsImpl(TcpSocketLink.java:1282)
    at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketLink.handleRequests(TcpSocketLink.java:1190)
    at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketLink.handleAcceptTaskImpl(TcpSocketLink.java:989)
    at com.caucho.network.listen.ConnectionTask.runThread(ConnectionTask.java:117)
    at com.caucho.network.listen.ConnectionTask.run(ConnectionTask.java:93)
    at com.caucho.network.listen.SocketLinkThreadLauncher.handleTasks(SocketLinkThreadLauncher.java:169)
    at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketAcceptThread.run(TcpSocketAcceptThread.java:61)
    at com.caucho.env.thread2.ResinThread2.runTasks(ResinThread2.java:173)
    at com.caucho.env.thread2.ResinThread2.run(ResinThread2.java:118)
```

---

it happens such kind of error for my resin webserver, I have several resin servers and only one server throw out such error suddenly.

Answer (score 2):

remove the resin-data diretory,then restart resin

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might have a database corruption there ...

Possibly related Resin bug report:  http://bugs.caucho.com/view.php?id=4956

The resolution for the bug report says "Fixed", so you should probably check your Resin installation is up to date.